# Show/hide content in menu on click and close button

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I'm looking for a plugin, preferably jQuery, that I can have the content hidden and then when you click one of the menu items it shows the content. However, the content doesn't hide until a user clicks on the close button. This theme uses that effect:

http://themetrust.com/demos/reveal/

Eexcept it's with the portfolio items instead of the menu items. I haven't been able to find anything and I'm hoping someone can lead me in the right direction.

Comment: See [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/). Both of the actions you're looking for will be handled by a click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example:

```
<div id="menu">
    <a href="first.html" rel="first">First</a>
    <a href="last.html" rel="last">Last</a>
</div>
<div id="first" class="content">
    First
    <input class="close" type="button" value="X"/>
</div>
<div id="last" class="content">
    Last
    <input class="close" type="button" value="X"/>
</div>

.content {
  display: none;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu a').click(function(){
        $('.content').hide();
        $('#'+this.rel+'').show();
        return false;
    });
    $('.content input.close').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().hide();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wm5Bh/

Comment: This works, but I wouldn't ever hide content with CSS, what if JS is turned off or doesn't load? You wouldn't ever see it. If you are showing content with JavaScript, hide it with JavaScript first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use jquery like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menuitem').click(function(){
              $('#content').show();
    })

 });
```

or use [`slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) instead of [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) for a nicer effect!

Declare your menuitem and your content with an id like:

```
<a href="x.php" id="menuitem">Menu</a>
<div id="content">Show me</div>
```

Remember that id's are unique!

Download jquery and link it in your html-header like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I just did a quick search on "jquery portfolio filter" and found some tuts on how to achieve this functionality/effect.

This [tut](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/06/beautiful-portfolio-html5-jquery/) achieves what you're after using jquery and the [Quicksand plugin](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/index.html).